# How extract id from react router with useparams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

this is  my code why it shows id undefined? i want in the sale component access to both title & id of each book but id is undefined.how can i show the value of id in the Sale component? thank you for your help!
`App.js`

```
  <Route path="books" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="books/:booktitle" element={<BookDetails />} />
  <Route path="books/:booktitle/sale/:id" element={<SaleStore />} />
```

`Dashbaord:`

```
 {books.map((book) => (
                  <div className="col" key={book.id}>
                    <div className="card h-100" >
                      <div className="card-img-top pb-5 mb-5">
                      </div>
                      <div className="card-body">
                        <Link to={`/books/${encodeURIComponent(book.title)}`}>
                          <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
                            {book.title}
                          </button>
                        </Link>
// rest of code
```

`Detail`:

```
  const { booktitle, id } = useParams();
  console.log("book Title:", booktitle);
  console.log("book Id:", id);
                     <Link to={`/books/${encodeURIComponent(booktitle)}/sale/${id}`}>
                          <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
                              go to sale
                          </button>
                        </Link>
```

`Sale`:

```
  const { booktitle, id } = useParams();
  console.log("book Title:", booktitle);
  console.log("book Id:",id);
  
        <p>{booktitle}</p> // 
      <p>{id}</p> // undefiend
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issue in the code you have shared, `const { booktitle, id } = useParams();` should do it. What is the URL path you are using? Are you sure the path and `SaleStore` component are correct and rendering? Is the `id` value correct in the `BookDetails` component rendering the `Link` to the sales page?

Comment: @DrewReese yes i can see the SaleStore component it shows title but id inside it is undefined. the url path is like this for SaleStore :/books/booktitle/sale/undefined
instead of undefined i want to show book id

Comment: You're trying to build a URL based on URL params that don't exist yet. In `Detail` the route does not have an `id` param. So it is undefined when you try to redirect to the `Sale` route

Comment: The `BookDetails` doesn't have an `id` value to pass to the link. Where does `BookDetails` get its book data?

Comment: @DrewReese in bookDetails i have these:
      const { booktitle } = useParams();
  console.log("book Title:", booktitle);
  <p >  {decodeURIComponent(booktitle)}</p> & it shows book title for me

Comment: @BrianThompson Ok, thanks for your help but how can i access to id in sale component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the `BookDetails` component has the undefined `id` param and passes it through to the link used to navigate to the sales page.

```
<Route
  path="books/:booktitle" // <-- no id param!
  element={<BookDetails />}
/>
```

```
const { booktitle, id } = useParams();
console.log("book Title:", booktitle);
console.log("book Id:", id); // <-- undefined

...

<Link
  to={`/books/${encodeURIComponent(booktitle)}/sale/${id}`} // <-- undefined id!
>
  ...
</Link>
```

I'd suggest a routing pattern where the book id is used earlier in the route path.

Exmaple:

```
<Route path="books">
  <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />         // "/books"
  <Route path=":title/:id">
    <Route index element={<BookDetails />} />.    // "/books/:title/:id"
    <Route path="sale" element={<SaleStore />} /> // "/books/:title/:id/sale"
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Update the dashboard to link to a detail page with title ***and*** id.

```
{books.map((book) => (
  <div className="col" key={book.id}>
    <div className="card h-100" >
      <div className="card-img-top pb-5 mb-5">
    </div>
    <div className="card-body">
      <Link to={`${book.title}/${book.id}`}> // "/books/:title/:id"
        <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
          {book.title}
        </button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```

Now both `title` and `id` will be defined int he details component. Link to the sales page.

```
const { title, id } = useParams();
console.log("book Title:", title);
console.log("book Id:", id);

...

<Link to="sale"> // "/books/:title/:id/sale"
  <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
    go to sale
  </button>
</Link>
```

Now the book `title` and `id` should also be available in the sale component.

Comment: code is correct for the first but for the second time it show not found page! why? <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} /> <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Layout component={Dashboard} />} /> <Route path="branches"> <Route index element={<Dashboard />} /> <Route path=":title/:id"> <Route index element={<BranchDetails />} />. <Route path="sale" element={<SaleStore />} /> </Route> </Route> <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />

Comment: @Negin If the page was found/reachable once, it should work each and every time. What is the URL when the page isn't found?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/dashboard/booktitle/bookid

Comment: @Negin So "bookTitle" and "bookid" became literal text in the URL path?

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you exacty say.  i just want to see this url:
"/books/:title/:id/sale" with sale component

Comment: @Negin FWIW the routing/navigation to the sale page and component is working as I'd expect here in this running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-extract-id-from-react-router-with-useparams-6vdrml?file=/src/App.js) demo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a route for Sale that includes both `:booktitle` and `:id` parameters:

```
<Route path="books/:booktitle/sale/:id" element={<SaleStore />} />
```

In your `Link` component in the BookDetails component, you are correctly constructing the URL:

```
<Link to={`/books/${encodeURIComponent(booktitle)}/sale/${id}`}>
  <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
    go to sale
  </button>
</Link>
```

However, when you use `useParams` in the Sale component, it seems that you might not be providing the `id` parameter correctly in the URL.

Make sure that when you navigate to the Sale component, you are providing both `:booktitle` and `:id` in the URL. For example, if you have a book with title "example" and ID "123", the URL should look like:

```
/books/example/sale/123
```

If the URL is correct, the `useParams` in the Sale component should correctly extract both `booktitle` and `id`. If it's still showing `undefined`, double-check the URL and make sure you are providing the parameters correctly. Additionally, you may want to log the entire `params` object to see what is being extracted:

```
const { booktitle, id } = useParams();
console.log("Params:", useParams());
console.log("book Title:", booktitle);
console.log("book Id:", id);
```

This way, you can inspect the entire `params` object and see if the parameters are being correctly parsed from the URL.

Comment: please don't just copy & paste chatgpt answers!